# Group By Dates Between with varchar data type in date column

Tags: mysql, sql

The Datatable of below query:
[image: The Datatable of below query]

```
SELECT delivery_datetime,SUM(total_bill)
FROM `load_information`
WHERE status='Delivered' AND
      delivery_datetime BETWEEN '04-01-2021' AND '04-31-2021'
GROUP BY delivery_datetime
HAVING delivery_datetime BETWEEN '04-01-2021' AND '04-31-2021' ORDER BY delivery_datetime ASC</pre>
```

**load_information** table structure

```
name              | type           | Collation
delivery_datetime | varchar(255)   | latin1_swedish_ci
total_bill        | float(10,2)
```

I can't change my `delivery_datetime` data type to **date()** or anything else
but I need to group by **delivery_datetime** and **SUM** of **total_bill** column.

Comment: What is your question?  And what date is `04-31-2021` supposed to be representing?

Comment: 1. Don't store dates as strings, there are DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP types for this. 2. If you _do_ store dates as strings, don't store them as anything other than `YYYY-MM-DD` so that you can at least sort and compare them without having to constantly convert their formats.

Comment: Store data using the correct data type for that data

Comment: @GordonLinoff The date ```04-31-2021``` is representing ```31st April 2021``` its in ```m-d-Y``` format.

Comment: @AunsuChandra . . . That is not a valid date on any calendar that I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't convert `delivery_datetime` to a `DATE` format, you're going to incur a significant performance penalty when trying to use it in date operation: it can't use indexes and will need to apply a conversion function over the entire table.

Having said that, this should do what you want:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(delivery_datetime,'%m-%d-%Y') AS delivery,
       SUM(total_bill) 
FROM `load_information` 
WHERE status = 'Delivered' 
  AND STR_TO_DATE(delivery_datetime,'%m-%d-%Y') BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2021-04-30' 
GROUP BY 1 
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want one row per *date* for each day in April, then cast the value to a date:

```
SELECT DATE(delivery_datetime), SUM(total_bill)
FROM `load_information`
WHERE status = 'Delivered' AND
      delivery_datetime >= '2021-04-01' AND
      delivery_datetime < '2021-05-01'
GROUP BY DATE(delivery_datetime)
```

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0012 seconds.)

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff's answer is good but, delivery_datetime is datetime column so we have to convert it to date first. Otherwise all records created within a day have different hour, minute and second. Therefore you cant group your one day data together. So do the following

```
SELECT DATE(delivery_datetime), SUM(total_bill)
FROM `load_information`
WHERE status = 'Delivered' AND
      Date(delivery_datetime) between '2021-04-01' AND '2021-05-01'
GROUP BY DATE(delivery_datetime)
```

Comment: I got an error on this @ASFAW
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delivery_datetime) between '2021-04-01' AND '2021-05-01'
GROUP BY DATE(delivery' at line 4

Comment: oh, you can change the convert(date, delivery_datetime) to DATE(delivery_datetime)